# python find first non-zero digit after decimal point

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Simple problem, how to find the first non-zero digit after decimal point. What I really need is the distance between the decimal point and the first non-zero digit.

I know I could do it with a few lines but I'd like to have some pythonic, nice and clean way to solve this.

So far I have this

```
>>> t = [(123.0, 2), (12.3, 1), (1.23, 0), (0.1234, 0), (0.01234, -1), (0.000010101, -4)]
>>> dist = lambda x: str(float(x)).find('.') - 1
>>> [(x[1], dist(x[0])) for x in t]
[(2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (-1, 0), (-4, 0)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be

```
x = 123.0
dist = int(math.log10(abs(x)))
```

I interpreted the second entry in each pair of the list `t` as your desired result, so I chose `int()` to round the logarithm towards zero:

```
>>> [(int(math.log10(abs(x))), y) for x, y in t]
[(2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (-1, -1), (-4, -4)]
```

Comment: Be sure to guard against negative values (can't take log of them) with abs.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Good point, but since I'm not yet sure this is what the OP is looking for at all, I'll wait a bit before I update the answer.

Comment: log(0) is not so good either. OP will probably need to special case this value (raise ValueError or return infinity?).

Comment: I used `math.floor` for more consistent results instead of `int`

Comment: I think it should be `math.ceil`!!!
For instance `-math.log10(0.0001) = 4.0`, and `math.log10(0.00011)= -2.999`. The latter gets rounded towards `-2`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

One way to focus on the digits after the decimal point is to remove the integer part of the number, leaving on the fractional part, with something like `x - int(x)`.

Having isolated the fractional part, you could let python do the counting for you with a `%e` presentation (that also helps take care of rounding issues).

```
>>> '%e' % 0.000125
'1.250000e-04'
>>> int(_.partition('-')[2]) - 1
3
```

Answer (score 2):

While this can technically be done with one line (excluding the import statement), I added a few extra things to make it more complete.

```
from re import search

# Assuming number is already defined.
# Floats always have a decimal in its string representation.
if isinstance(float, number):
    # This gets the substring of zeros immediately following the decimal point
    # and returns the length of it.
    return len(search("\.(0*)", "5.00060030").group(1))
else:
    return -1
    # or you can use raise TypeError() if you wanna be more restrictive.
```

This probably isn't of any concern to you but I thought I'd mention it for sake of completeness, in some regions, periods and commas are swapped when it comes to numbers. For example 1,000,000.00 could be 1.000.000,00. Not sure if Python acknowledges this but since it doesn't represent any numbers with thousands separators, you could use the pattern `,(0*)` for the other regions. Again, probably doesn't matter to you but it may to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
ZerosCount = math.ceil(-math.log10(abs(value) - abs(math.floor(value)))) - 1
```

Comment: Please explain what that does.

Comment: Index of first non zero value in chars array float decimal part.

Comment: It's better to include the explanation of the code into the answer, so the next reader won't need to delve into the comments